# Unable to delete file from storage

Tags: android, file, storage

I am trying to delete a file from the phone storage but its always returning false. I have already tried most of the methods given on stack but nothing is working.

```
 final File file = new File(path);
        if (path != null) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog
                    .Builder(getContext()).setTitle("Delete")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this video?")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                               boolean fileDeleted =  file.delete();
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(fileDeleted), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show();
        }
```

Comment: What exception are you gettings?

Comment: do you have storage permission granted?

Comment: @Sunny yeah i have taken both read and write permission

Comment: @SomeshKumar I am not getting any exceptions its just returning value false as the code is not working

Comment: `new File(path);` What is the value of path? You should have started with it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code i used after trying many methods.

```
private static boolean delete(final Context context, final File file) {
    final String where = MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=?";
    final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
            file.getAbsolutePath()
    };
    final ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    final Uri filesUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");

    contentResolver.delete(filesUri, where, selectionArgs);

    if (file.exists()) {

        contentResolver.delete(filesUri, where, selectionArgs);
    }
    return !file.exists();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
public class FileUtils {

    public static boolean deleteFile(File file, Context context) {
        if (file == null || !file.exists()) return true;
        file.delete();
        if (file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.getCanonicalFile().delete();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (file.exists()) context.deleteFile(file.getName());
        }
        return !file.exists();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

show me your file path which you are passing into the file,if you write the file into the SD card you will not able to delete it Because
From Android 4.4 on apps cannot write to a micro SD card anymore.

Comment: I am passing it from content resolver .I am searching for all the videos available on the device and adding it to an array list.

Comment: `I am passing it from content resolver` Can be. And that looks already problematic.  But show us one path of a file. You should have started with it. I think it is not a path to a classic file. Does the path start with content:// ?